# Creating a namespace using a class defined in another namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I was trying out the following code whether it works or not. Need help whether it could be done in any other way.

```
 // FOO.hpp
 namespace traits {
   class FOO {
       public:
        typedef std::vector<int>     vec_t;
        typedef std::map <int, int>  map_t;
   };
  };

 namespace my_traits = traits::FOO;
 //I know the compile will give the error as "FOO" is not a namespace-name. 

 // in BAR.hpp
 using namespace my_traits;
 class BAR {
   private:
     vec_t  my_vector;   //  my_traits will have FOO's members (typedefs)
     map_t  my_map;      //  my_traits will have FOO's members (typedefs)
  };




  I **don't** want to do the following :
  using namespace traits;
  class BAR {
    private:
      traits::FOO::vec_t  my_vector  //  AVOID
      traits::FOO::map_t  my_map     //  AVOID
  }
```

But essentially I want to put all the typedefs  in class FOO and then use FOO as a namespace. I dont want to put typdefs in any namespace as such.

Is that possible in C++11 (or in general C++).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a `class` as a `namespace`, you have to use a real `namespace`:

```
namespace traits {
    namespace FOO {
        typedef std::vector<int>     vec_t;
        typedef std::map <int, int>  map_t;
    };
};

namespace my_traits = traits::FOO;
```

```
using namespace my_traits;
class BAR {
private:
    vec_t  my_vector;   //  my_traits will have FOO's members (typedefs)
    map_t  my_map;      //  my_traits will have FOO's members (typedefs)
};
```

Comment: well yes. I can do this. but that is not I want as such. may be there is no way. my class FOO will be templatized further over partial types such as vector  and int . For eg. I pass std::vector and std::int as template parameter to FOO. So I can create a container with vector<int>. If I pass std::set and std::int FOO will have typedef as set<int> my_container_t .. This class FOO  will further be passed as template class to another class BAR  to create private members as  my_container_t  my_container.  Hope it is clear

Comment: You cannot templatize a namespace. So what you are asking for is basically not possible. Try something like this: `namespace traits { template<typename T>class FOO { typedef std::vector<T> vec_t; typedef std::map<T> map_t; }; };` and then `using traits::FOO<int>::vec_t; using traits::FOO<int>::map_t; vec_t my_vector; map_t my_map;`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to adapt to what you describe in the comments below Remy's solution:

If `BAR` **is not a class template**, you have the following option:

```
namespace traits
{
    template<typename T>
    struct FOO
    {
        using vec_t = std::vector<T>;
        using map_t = std::map<int, T>;
    };
};

// in BAR.hpp

class BAR : traits::FOO<int>
{
    vec_t my_vector;
    map_t my_map;
};
```

So the type aliases become available in `BAR` by inheriting the concrete class `FOO<int>`, where `FOO` is a class template as you requested. This is quite convenient.

However, if `BAR` **is a class template** itself like

```
template<typename F>
class BAR : F { ... }
```

(e.g. where `F` is `FOO<T>` for some `T`) then the above does not apply so conveniently: you have to declare

```
using vec_t = typename F::vec_t;
using map_t = typename F::map_t;
```

for every alias of `F` you want to use. However, even if you don't make these aliases, you can still say

```
F::vec_t my_vector;
F::map_t my_map;
```

which is not too bad.